# Is it possible to return to the Lucis that takes place in Chapter 14? (potential spoilers)

Tags: final-fantasy-15

In the chapter 14, before heading to the Kingdom of Lucis, Noctis

> finds himself in a world covered in darkness and overrun by high level daemons.

When I first came to this part of the story, I was not strong enough to fight these daemons and was forced to continue.

I have since beaten the main story and completed the post-game content in chapter 15 and my character's level has increased to a point where I have a chance against the daemons within chapter 14.

Is it possible to return to the Lucis where Chapter 14 takes place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the recent [update version 1.14](https://gematsu.com/2017/08/final-fantasy-xv-version-1-15-update-now-available), a new chapter select mode has been implemented once you have completed the main story.

> **Version 1.14**
>
> - Implementation of a chapter select (available after completion of the main game)

This feature will allow you to select and re-play through any chapter in the game while keeping your characters levels and inventory.

Answer (score 2):

According to a post in [this thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/932981-final-fantasy-xv/74679842?jumpto=2), no, you cannot return to future Lucis.

> Nope. After you beat the game the game makes you create a save file for future use. You are then sent before the fight with ifrit and from that safe room you can use umbra to return to the past. Future Lucis is not an option.

I believe that this save file is beyond a point of no return, which means you won't be able to leave the area and return to open world future Lucis.

That said, I haven't seen any evidence of there being sidequests in Chapter 14's future Lucis, though, so I don't think you're really missing anything.

Since there isn't a way to do so in NG, the only way for you to fully explore future Lucis would be to progress your NG+ file to that point. Since you retain levels, you won't have much need to grind in order to stand a chance against the high level daemons.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong (I haven't been able to play the game since last month), but if you do New Game+ and progress through the story, you can revisit future Lucis. I believe levels carry over?

Comment: @LOL.NO. Yes, that's correct, but my understanding of the question was that OP wanted to explore future Lucis in NG, rather than get all the way back to that point in a NG+ run. I updated my answer to include this information, though. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Vemonus is correct. Rather than doing another run through, I wanted to know if I could travel back without NG+

Comment: @Wondercricket Thanks for the clarification! Just wasn't sure if you were considering NG+ as an answer.

Comment: Isn't it actually possible to go through point of no return second time, and get to future Lucis in common way second time?

Comment: @lentinant what do you mean? You can't use umbra to go to a different point of chapter 14 from where it lets you save after the point of no return right before ifrit.

Comment: @Vemonus I mean, on chapter 13, you have last checkpoint, where you can go back to Lucis, and if you go further, you get to chapter 14. Once you finish the game, you are back at this checkpoint in chapter 13, with all the stuff you got. What if you just progress through chapter? Won't you get to content of chapter 14?

Comment: @lentinant, no, once you complete chapter 14, you are sent back to the point of no return in chapter 14. Sure, you can beat the final boss again, but you are not able to explore future Lucis as you could in chapter 13.

Comment: Who needs sidequests?  Future Lucis is bleak and awesome.  I just want to see angry Noct carve a swathe of death and destruction across the countryside, leaving a trail of dead daemons in his wake.